# WP 8.1 Searching for calendar control

Tags: calendar, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm developing an app for windows phone 8.1, and now I need a calendar control like the calendar app of the phone. I've tried winrttoolkit for windows phone, but in that calendar I cannot write on the cells of the days. I want to write something inside the cells.

Anyone can help me? A free control or some code please!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has the calendar ported from Silverlight Toolkit and has the source. You can check if it is possible to template it in such a way to have tap/editable days. Maybe someone has already done it for SLTK? You can check the commercial component libraries I list on the CodePlex page, but I think modding the one from the Toolkit is your best bet...

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. For now I don't want to edit source code, if  it is possible.